# How to access other project forms in solution explorer for VS2008 C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, explorer

[Image http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/1720/28264117.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/1720/28264117.png)

Here is the image for my solution Explorer. What i want is to use HR Management forms to b loaded through button click on a form of Classic Steel HR. So can anyone tell me how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your image here, unfortunately - but if I get what you're trying to ask; you can access forms from another assembly if they're public.

Then just check this setting is true:

Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : AutoToolboxPopulate

Alternatively:

Alternatively, you need to make sure that the HR project is referenced by the Classic_steel_hr project then in your forms code (assuming it's namespace is HR)

```
using HR;

private void ShowForm()
{
  HR.Form1 hrForm = new HR.Form1();
  hrForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: am trying alot for that hosting but image doesn't show up i always end up having an error image thats why well thanks buddy letme try your way

Comment: I've just opened the link manually, it looks like what I suggested above should work.